# Xubuntu too slow on Dell Xps L501x

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu, nvidia-geforce

I have a Dell XPS L501X laptop with following specifications:

- Intel(R) Core(TM) i3 CPUM 370@2.40GHz
- Nvidia GT420M 1GB Graphics card
- 4GB DDR3 Ram
- 500 GB SATA Hard drive

I was a windows 10 user, but for a change I switched to ubuntu 16.04. I had a clean installation of Ubuntu 16.04 on this system. But the system was too slow, especially the browsers. I googled the solutions, and found that I must change the desktop **from Unity to Xfce**.

I followed the instructions of this website [From Unity to Xfce: Ubuntu 16.04 becomes Xubuntu 16.04](https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/alternative).
This did not solve the problem though, the system is still slow. I have installed proprietary Nvidia drivers(version 367.57 from nvidia-367).

*Edit:* *Slow here means very sluggish. Once the system boots the system performs well for 10-15 minutes but after that it becomes very sluggish specially when I use any browser or play any multimedia file. Sometimes the system freezes*

Comment: What Nvidia drivers version have you installed and how? Please edit the question and add that information.

Comment: Also please define "slow"... Apps taking a long time to open and/or running sluggishly is *my* definition of slow. The *especially the browsers* suggest a problem with the internet connection.

Comment: @CelticWarrior I have updated my question. Hope it helps. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Switch on your computer.

Wait until the BIOS has finished loading, and `press and hold` the `Shift key`, which will bring up the Grub menu.

Select the line which starts with `Advanced options`.

Select the line ending with `(recovery mode)`

Press `Return` and your machine will begin the boot process.

After a few moments, your PC should display a menu with a number of options.

One of the options will be `Drop to root shell prompt`.

Press `Return` with this option highlighted.

The pc will start in a terminal, run it:

```
mount -o remount,rw /
mount --all
apt-get update
apt-get install --reinstall aptitude deborphan
aptitude remove '?and(?reverse-depends(ubuntu),?not(?reverse-depends(?exact-name(xubuntu-desktop))))'
aptitude remove '?and(?reverse-depends(gnome),?not(?reverse-depends(?exact-name(xubuntu-desktop))))'
aptitude remove '?and(?reverse-depends(unity),?not(?reverse-depends(?exact-name(xubuntu-desktop))))'
apt-get install --reinstall xubuntu-desktop
deborphan
apt-get --purge remove $(deborphan)
deborphan --libdevel
apt-get --purge remove $(deborphan --libdevel)
deborphan --find-config
dpkg --purge $(deborphan --find-config)
apt-get autoremove
apt-get clean
reboot
```

*Edit: Starts in text-only mode. Mount partitions in read-write mode. 
Update repositories. Install aptitude and deborphan. It eliminates the components of Ubuntu that are not necessary in Xfce. It eliminates the components of gnome that are not necessary in Xfce. It eliminates the components of unity that are not necessary in Xfce. Reinstall Xubuntu-desktop.
Eliminates orphan packages. Removes unnecessary packages. Removes downloaded packages. Restart System.*

Comment: What it does, could you please explain it.